# Today extension: syncing data with container app

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

#### Context

I've been playing around with Today Extensions using [this example project](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/AppExtensionsDemo).

The app is quite simple:

- In the containing app, you have a list of todo items, which you can mark completed
- In the Today widget, you see the same list, but you can switch between completed, and incomplete items using a segmented control.

My goal is the following: whenever there is a data change, either in the container app, or the widget, I want both to reflect the changes:

- If I mark an item as completed in the container app, then pull down the Notification Center, the widget should be updated
- When I do the same in the widget, then return to the app, the app's state should be updated

#### The implementation

I understand, that the container app, and the extension run in their separate processes, which means two constraints:

- `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` is useless.
- Managing the model instances in memory is useless.

I also know, that in order to access a shared container, both targets must opt-in to the App Groups entitlements under the same group Id.

The data access is managed by an embedded framework, [TodoKit](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/AppExtensionsDemo/blob/master/TodoKit/Data/ShoppingItemStore.swift). Instead of keeping properties in memory, it goes straight to `NSUserDefaults` for the appropriate values:

```
public struct ShoppingItemStore: ShoppingStoreType {

    private let defaultItems = [
        ShoppingItem(name: "Coffee"),
        ShoppingItem(name: "Banana"),
    ]

    private let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupId)

    public init() {}

    public func items() -> [ShoppingItem] {
        if let loaded = loadItems() {
            return loaded
        } else {
            return defaultItems
        }
    }

    public func toggleItem(item: ShoppingItem) {

        let initial = items()

        let updated = initial.map { original -> ShoppingItem in
            return original == item ?
                ShoppingItem(name: original.name, status: !original.status) : original
        }

        saveItems(updated)
    }

    private func saveItems(items: [ShoppingItem]) {

        let boxedItems = items.map { item -> [String : Bool] in
            return [item.name : item.status]
        }

        defaults?.setValue(boxedItems, forKey: savedDataKey)
        defaults?.synchronize()
    }

    private func loadItems() -> [ShoppingItem]? {

        if let loaded = defaults?.valueForKey(savedDataKey) as? [[String : Bool]] {

            let unboxed = loaded.map { dict -> ShoppingItem in

                return ShoppingItem(name: dict.keys.first!, status: dict.values.first!)
            }

            return unboxed
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

#### The problem

Here's what works:

- When I modify the list in my main app, then **stop the simulator**, and then launch the Today target from Xcode, it reflects the correct state. This is true vice-versa.

This verifies, that my app group is set up correctly.

However, when I change something in the main app, then pull down the Notification Center, it is completely out of sync. And this is the part, which I don't understand.

My views get their data straight from the shared container. Whenever a change happens, I immediately update the data in the shared container.

What am I missing? How can I sync up these two properly? My data access class is not managint *any* state, yet I don't understand why it doesn't behave correctly.

#### Additional info

- I know about [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole). Unfortunately this is not an option for me, since I need to reach proper functionality without including any third party solutions.
- This [terrific article](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions), covers the topic, and it might be possible, that I need to employ `NSFilePresenter`, although it seems cumbersome, and I don't completely understand the mechanism yet. I really hope, there is an easier solution, than this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have learned two things here:

First of all, **Always** double check your entitlements, mine somehow got messed up, and that's why the shared container behaved so awkwardly.

Second: 
Although `viewWillAppear(_:)` is not called, when you dismiss the notification center, it's still possible to trigger an update from your app delegate:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(updateDataNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Then in your view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(updateDataNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (_) -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Updating your Today widget is simple: each time the notification center is pulled down, `viewWillAppear(:_)` is called, so you can query for new data there.

I'll update the example project on GitHub shortly.